# toString not working in my class

Tags: java

My problem > The toString has an error saying that i havent added a return;

What i did,
i made a class that generates either a random Luck or a random Time

```
public randomLuckOrTime(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int t = rand.nextInt(2);

    if(t == 0){
        randomTime();
    }
    else if(t == 1){
        randomLuck();
    }

}
```

The two Classes

```
public Luck randomLuck(){

    int [] num = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,6,6,9,17};


    Luck q = new Luck();
    Random rand = new Random();

    int Rand = rand.nextInt(15);
    q.setLuck(num[Rand]);
    this.numbr = q.getLuck();


    return q;

}

public Time randomTime(){

    int [] TImeList = {10,20,30,40,50};

    Time l = new Time();
    Random rand = new Random();

    int Rand = rand.nextInt(5);
    l.setTime(TimeList[Rand]);
    this.Time = l.getTime();

    return l;
}
```

my toString which i want to vary depending on which option of the two is being printed out.

```
public String toString(){
    if(this.Time == 0){
        String s = " " +"\n";
        s += "Random Number: " + this.numbr+ "\n";

        return s;
    }
    else if(this.numbr = 0){
        String s = " " +"\n";
        s += "Random Time: " + this.Time+ "\n";

        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error because neither condition might be `true`, and thus you would have no `return`. If you do something like,

```
String s = " " +"\n";
if(this.Time == 0){
    s += "Random Number: " + this.numbr+ "\n";
}
else if(this.numbr == 0){ // <-- note ==
    s += "Random Time: " + this.Time+ "\n";
}
return s;
```

There's less code as well as it being legal code. Alternatively, you could eliminate `s` and do something like

```
if(this.Time != 0){
    return String.format("Random Time: %d%n" + this.Time);
}
else if(this.numbr != 0){
    return String.format("Random Number: %d%n", this.numbr);
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 2):

If both `if` conditions fail, you "fall through" and so no return.

`this.numbr = 0` is an assignment not a test.